# Guzzle not correctly firing requests

Tags: php, curl, caching, guzzle

I'm running a Lightspeed server and using their built-in LS Cache to cache the pages.

I'm writing a plugin to fire purge requests to the cache when a page is saved, however I can't seem to get Guzzle to correctly send the batched requests.

I'm not getting an error from Guzzle, but I can't see any PURGE requests hitting the server. However, if I run it through cURL instead, it works great.

**Guzzle**

```
$batch = \Guzzle\Batch\BatchBuilder::factory()
    ->transferRequests(20)
    ->bufferExceptions()
    ->build();

$client = new \Guzzle\Http\Client();
$client->setDefaultOption('headers/Accept', '*/*');

foreach ($paths as $path)
{
  $request = $client->createRequest('PURGE', $path);
  $request->setProtocolVersion('1.0');
  $request->addHeader('Host', 'mydomain.com');
  $batch->add($request);
}

$requests = $batch->flush();
$batch->clearExceptions();
```

**cURL**

```
foreach ($paths as $path)
{
  $curl = curl_init($path);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PURGE");
  curl_exec($curl);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, try to migrate to Guzzle 6.x, because Guzzle 3.x (that you are using) is outdated and unsupported.

With Guzzle 6.x it should look like

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

$requestGenerator = function () use ($client, $paths) {
    foreach ($paths as $path) {
        yield $client->requestAsync('PURGE', $path);
    }
}

$allRequests = \GuzzleHttp\Promise\each_limit(
    $requestGenerator(), 
    5 // How many concurrent requests should be done?
);

$allRequests->wait();
```

The code above is a bit complicated than yours, but it has a big advantage — concurrency. For your task it's a big improvement, IMO.

Comment: I've added Guzzle 6 as a dependency and plugged this code in, and now the requests are being sent successfully! Thanks Alexey.